# flutter sliver persistent header

Tags: flutter, dart

I have UI design like follow. Actually I have done using Stack. Now requirement is that I need to show small circle image and title on app bar when scroll up.

The white area is using flutter_html widget. I tried to use sliver persistent header but I can't move html widget container under image container. I can do it html container below image container.

Is there a way to do it?

Requirement

[image: Requirement]

This is how achieved so far
[image: This is how achieved so far]

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
import 
  'package:sliver_header_delegate/sliver_header_delegate.dart';
import 'package:thitsarparami/blocs/bloc.dart';
import 
'package:thitsarparami/ui/error/something_went_wrong.dart';

class SliverBiographyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/biography';
  const SliverBiographyScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SliverBiographyScreen> createState() => 
_SliverBiographyScreenState();
}

class _SliverBiographyScreenState extends 
State<SliverBiographyScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadAbout();
  }

  _loadAbout() async {
    BlocProvider.of<AboutBloc>(context).add(const 
 GetAboutEvent());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double screenHeight = 
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
  body: BlocBuilder<AboutBloc, AboutState>(
    builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is AboutError) {
        return const SomethingWentWrongScreen();
      } else if (state is AboutLoaded) {
        return CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              pinned: true,
              delegate: FlexibleHeaderDelegate(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  statusBarHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
                  expandedHeight: 240,
                  background: MutableBackground(
                    expandedWidget: Container(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: 150,
                            height: 150,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: screenHeight * 0.09,
                              left: (screenWidth - 150) / 2,
                              right: (screenWidth - 150) / 2,
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                                width: 2,
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                imageUrl: state.about.headMonkImageUrl!,
                                imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) =>
                                    Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    border: Border.all(
                                      color: Theme.of(context)
                                          .primaryColorDark,
                                      width: 4,
                                    ),
                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                      image: imageProvider,
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    collapsedColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                  children: [
                    FlexibleTextItem(
                      //textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      text: 'သစ္စာပါရမီဆရာတော်ထေရုပ္ပတ္တိ',
                      collapsedStyle: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .headline2!
                          .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                      expandedStyle: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .headline2!
                          .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                      expandedAlignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      collapsedAlignment: Alignment.center,
                      expandedPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
                    ),
                  ]),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50),
                  child: Flexible(
                    child: Html(
                      data: state.about.biography,
                      style: {
                        "body": Style(
                            fontSize: const FontSize(18.0),
                            //fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            lineHeight: LineHeight.em(1.5)),
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      }
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    },
  ),
);
  }
}
```

Comment: have you try floating = true  option ?

Comment: @RohitChaurasiya I think that my explanation is not good enough. I will add the sliver persistent header code as well. So that you will see the current result that I got now.